# How to connect with md5 hashed password?

Tags: npgsql

I would like to pass an md5 hashed password in the Connection string of npgsql. Is it possible?

if so, from which string do I need to generate the md5 hash?

thanks

Comment: Npgsql takes care of doing MD5 hashing itself. That is, you provide it a cleartext password and it will send an MD5 hash of that to PostgreSQL, if that's what requested. What exactly are you trying to achieve, are you running into some issue?

Comment: What I tried to do is store the password md5 hashed on the client computer, so the user doesn't have to enter it every time. Apparently this is not possible, so I have to store it cleartext.

Comment: That's currently not possible, you can open an issue to request this. You may also want to look into SSPI/GSS (AKA integrated security) where no passwords are used at all - this is the safest way to log in, and doesn't require any passwords.